# Symfony2: Dynamic Routing Prefix

Tags: php, symfony

I need to create a dynamic routing scheme, where I am prefixing the routes with a variable that changes.

Here's an example:

Application Base Route: /dashboard/

Scenario A: /client_a/dashboard/
Scenario B: /client_b/dashboard/
Scenario C: /client_c/dashboard/

The idea is to keep the application core code all the same, but allow different clients to be referenced in the route.

What's best practice to set this up? I can add a static prefix in the routing.yml, but unless the '`prefix: /myparameter`' can be set up dynamically, this may not work for me. Primary reason for this is an existing Symfony2 application that is quite complex.

If I am using `/{client_name}/dashboard/`, I'll have to change all the paths in the application, since now I have an additional parameter missing in the route. So, I am looking for a solution that allows me to retrofit the existing application without necessarily having to touch the application main code.

Thanks,

JB

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but can't you just route `/{client_name}/dashboard` to your controller?

Comment: Certainly. What I am trying to figure out is a way to retrofit an already existing Symfony2 app without having to touch all the routes in the routing.yml and the paths in the Twig templates. Thus the question about the prefix.

Comment: Maybe you should put an extract of you routing file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jakub's comment is essentially correct. However, if, as in my case, an existing Symfony app has to be retrofitted for this new requirement, it is extremely tedious. There is furthermore an issue with the security implementation in Symfony in that Symfony requires static paths for the login, login_check, and logout methods. So, any use of the prefix in those scenarios doesn't seem to be currently supported.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem. I would also like to skip the dynamic parameter in some cases. The "client" or other entity is sometimes identified by the route parameter and sometimes by http host.